# Exception handling and monad transformers

Tags: haskell, exception, monads, monad-transformers

I'm writing an application with a text-based user interface using [brick](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/brick).
I'm trying to add exception handling to my event loop without success.
I'd like that when an action fails in my app, an exception is thrown, caught, and a notification displayed in some kind of modal, explaining the reason of the failure.

My event handling function, which is called every time there is a keyboard event like a key pressed, looks like this:

```
appEvent :: AppState UIName -> BrickEvent UIName MPDEvent -> EventM UIName (Next (AppState UIName))
appEvent state event = E.catchAny (handleAppEvent state event) (handleException state)
```

And this is how I handle events and exceptions:

```
handleAppEvent :: AppState UIName -> BrickEvent UIName MPDEvent -> EventM UIName (Next (AppState UIName))
handleAppEvent state event = case event of
    VtyEvent (Vty.EvKey (Vty.KChar 'e') []) -> liftIO $ E.throwM MPDException
    e -> handleViewEvent state e

handleException :: AppState n -> SomeException -> EventM n (Next (AppState n))
handleException state ex =  M.continue $ state & notificationState %~ (Notification.setNotification "Excpetion")
```

I had to write the following instances for my program to compile:

```
import qualified Control.Exception.Safe as E
import Control.Monad.Catch (MonadCatch(..))

instance E.MonadThrow (EventM n) where
  throwM e = liftIO $ E.throwM e


instance E.MonadCatch (EventM n) where
  catch = E.catch
```

[EventM](https://github.com/jtdaugherty/brick/blob/master/src/Brick/Types.hs#L116-L119) is this:

```
newtype EventM n a =
    EventM { runEventM :: ReaderT (EventRO n) (StateT (EventState n) IO) a
           }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)
```

Now my program compiles but doesn't work correctly. It shows the starting screen but I can't do anything, as if the `handleAppEvent` function wasn't run.

Comment: Of course it hangs! `E.catch` is defined in terms of `MonadCatch.catch` - you have a patently infinite loop. The `throw` function is fine because you are using `E.throwM :: Exception -> IO a` whereas `E.catch` is used at the type `EventM n a -> (Exception -> EventM n a) -> EventM n a`.